# Interface v Class tree structure

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013

I am working on an existing Asp.Net application using VS 2013.  I am trying to add some interfaces and classes to it and I would like to keep things in sync as much as possible, including the design, structure etc.

I can create/add an Interface and a Class, but I can't make them appear within the same Node as in the picture.  The existing Interface and the Class showing within the same Node/tree structure.  I've googled around but so far couldn't find a solution.  Can anyone please provide a suggestion on how to put Interface and a Class withing the same tree structure in a Solution Explorer? Thanks

[image: VS 2013 Solution Explorer view]

Comment: What sense does interface have so strongly coupled with its implementation? Please look for "entourage anti-pattern".

Comment: You appear to have somehow put `UserRepository.cs` inside `IUserRepository.cs`. I don't follow how you did that.

Comment: @KonradKokosa, the description of the "entourage anti-pattern" at https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=EJ_HBAAAQBAJ&pg=PT129&lpg=PT129&dq=entourage+anti-pattern&source=bl&ots=19KxJCRjzX&sig=aV2rnnpx5KheUldKC4J98qqJcm4&hl=en&sa=X&ei=swZfVaSAN8ftUuSTgcAD&ved=0CEkQ6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=entourage%20anti-pattern&f=false makes no sense to me as it argues the false position that having both the interface and class in the same assembly means they both need to be public.

Comment: I will agree with you, but all the Interfaces and classes were done in this way by previous developer, so I just want to add few items in the same structure.  Can anyone please suggest how?

Comment: I still would like to know if anyone knows how to attach an implementation to an interface as the above figure please?

Comment: Has anyone got an answer on the above question?